# Ошибка считывания/записи переменной в 3х потоках с использованием atomic и без (с++)

Tags: c++, многопоточность, atomic

У нас есть 2 потока, которые асинхронно записывают в переменную tmp числа 322 и 1337. Странность в том, что даже если переменная atomic, условие все-таки иногда срабатывает (причем даже намного чаще, чем если бы переменная было просто int), но в cout все-таки вводится либо 1337 или 322. Объясните пожалуйста как все-таки защитить переменную от считывания во время записи. Казалось бы что на 32битных системах все переменные до 4 байт должны записываться атомарно.
Вот код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
    atomic<int> tmp = 322;
    thread th0([&tmp]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { tmp = 322; this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(2));
        }
    });
    thread th1([&tmp]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { tmp = 1337; this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(3));
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        if(tmp!=322&&tmp!=1337)cout << "Ошибка =" <<tmp<< endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(1));
    }
    th0.detach();
    th1.detach();
}
```

Comment: Используйте встроенные функции замены значения. `tmp.store(322);`. Я не уверен, что оператор присвоения у атомика атомарный.

Comment: Попробовал и store и load. Ничего не помогает, все работает аналогично.

Comment: у atomic нет функций `operator!=`

Comment: Даже если сделать условие таким if(tmp.load()!=322&&tmp.load()!=1488) программа работает аналогично (а ведь load возвращает int)

Comment: `tmp.load` нужно вызвать _один_ раз. Результат сохранить в переменную. Эту переменную потом сравнивать.

Comment: `&&` не атомарна

Comment: @PavelGridin - верните свой ответ и дополните.

Comment: Alexander Petrov прав и суть ,видимо, в этом и есть. Судя по "экспериментам" load использовать не обязательно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все тут атомарно (естественно, кроме вычисления всего выражения в `if`).

А чего вы ожидали?

Объявив `tmp` atomic вы заставили компилятор обращаться к памяти при каждом упоминании `tmp`.

Соответственно, в `if(tmp!=322&&tmp!=1337)` значение `tmp` будет выбираться дважды.
Если первое чтение вернуло 1337, а второе 322, то выполнится

`cout << "Ошибка =" <<tmp<< endl;`,

что вы иногда (думаю, довольно редко) и наблюдаете.

Answer (score 4):

Операции `tmp!=322` и `tmp!=1337` не атомарны, так как std::atomic не имеет функций operator!=, и даже если бы имел то операция && между ними точно не атомарна

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что пока происходит проверка на условие, переменная иногда успевает менять свое значение. Для того чтобы избежать такой проблемы, нужно сохранить во временную переменную значение переменной перед началом проверки

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    int ntmp = tmp;
    if(ntmp !=322&& ntmp !=1337)cout << "Ошибка =" <<ntmp<< endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
}
```

Comment: `std::atomic<int> ntmp = tmp;` иначе во время присвоения может случится бардак

Comment: @PavelGridin, никакого "бардака" с `ntmp` не случится. В любом случае компилятор сгенерит команду чтения из памяти в регистр, который далее в коде будет использован как `ntmp`